# MP3 encoding problems caused by gstreamer1.0 lamemp3enc not working (for me) in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, gstreamer, lame, soundconverter

After a fresh install of 16.04, I am no longer able to convert sound files to MP3. It works neither in Rhythmbox, Sound-Juicer or Soundbridge nor can I use gat-launch-1.0 to create a pipeline manually that contains lamemp3enc. Using gst-inspect-1.0 also shows that the lame plugin is not installed in gstreamer.

I have ensured that both lame and the lame libraries are installed as well as the gstreamer 1.0 plugin-ugly (and good and bad), so all dependencies are met. I've checked that libtwolame.so and libgstlame.so is installed, and that the later refers to libmp3lame.so, which is also installed.

I can use lame directly from the command line. I can of course also use ffmpeg or selene (that do not use the gstreamer framework), so as a workaround I can use other apps.

But is this an error somehow in the gstreamer 1.0 plugins-ugly package? Or some issue with my AMD64 installation? Any hints as how to further debug this via gstreamer?